# Surjectivity of J homomorphism

Tags: algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles, higher-homotopy-groups

Can somebody say something about surjectivity of the $J$ homomorphism $J_{7,7}$ : $\pi_{7}$SO($7$) $\rightarrow$ $\pi_{14}(S^7)$ ? Husemoller in Fibre Bundles says this :[image: Proposition 6.4]

Where $M_{n}^{1}$ denotes component of $\text{Map}_{0}(S^{n-1},S^{n-1})$ consisting of maps of degree $1$. I do not know how to proceed after this. Also is there any information about unstable $J$ homomorphisms ?

Comment: Are you asking specifically about the unstable case, or are you also interested in the story of $J$ in the stable regime?

Comment: Could you pull it out of the Hopf fibration for $S^7$?

Comment: @anomaly I am asking about unstable case.  Also i do not understand what do you mean by pull it out of Hopf fibration.

Comment: It was just an idle thought, but the idea was that the long exact sequence corresponding to the fibration $S^3 \to S^7 \to S^4$ has the $S^3$ and $S^4$ terms in the stable range when you look at $\pi_{14}(S^7)$, but I don't know how the $J$-homomorphism behaves under it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not surjective.  More specifically, using a table of homotopy groups of spheres on Wikipedia, I can prove that this map is not surjective.  But I cannot speak to the veracity of the table.

The key observation is Proposition 6.4 which tells you that $J = E\circ \theta \circ\epsilon_\ast$.  Note, then, that if $E$ is not surjective, $J$ cannot possible be surjective.

According to [this Table of homotopys groups of spheres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_groups_of_spheres#Table_of_homotopy_groups), $\pi_{13}(S^6)\cong \mathbb{Z}_{60}$ while $\pi_{14}(S^7) \cong \mathbb{Z}_{120}$.  Thus, $E$ is obviously not surjective: its image consists of at most half the elements in $\pi_{14}(S^7)$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is it possible to say something about the size of the image of J ?

Comment: @SAR:  I know too little about $J$ to say anything more, sorry.  Someone more knowledgeable may be able to provide details.

Comment: I think this result in Huesmollar book in not for every $r$ and $n$. As $J_{3,3}$ is surjective but according to above factorization it should not be.

Comment: @SAR:  I'm sorry, this is just not a story I know any details about.